# Table view cell's label won't center align unless number of lines is 1

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, uilabel

I have a UITableViewCell subclass alone in a xib.  The cell has a UILabel subview in it.  The text alignment in IB is set to center, but unless `numberOfLines` is set to 1, the label snaps over to left alignment (even though the "Alignment" in IB is set to center sill).  I tried setting the `textAlignment` to `NSTextAlignmentCenter` in the cell's `awakeFromNib`, and also in the corresponding table view's `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`,
but still no luck, even though when I check the cell's `textAlignment` value at various breakpoints it's `NSTextAlignmentCenter`.

How can I center align multiple lines of text in a UILabel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, right after I post the question, I figure it out.

If the "Autoshrink" has "Tighten Letter Spacing" selected in IB, it snaps it to the left alignment.  Uncheck this to have it stay centered.